# When using `byobu` in a PuTTY session cannot create new windows

Tags: byobu, putty

I have an *Ubuntu 10.04.4* web server, and I have set it to run **byobu** on session startup.

To start with it all seems to work fine, for example <kbd>F9</kbd> brings up the menu and <kbd>F7</kbd> starts the copy/paste process.

When I connect to the server using PuTTY from my PC, the problem is that when I press <kbd>F2</kbd> to create a new window, the screen just flashes, and no window is created.

I have tried setting PuTTY to use `Xterm R6` in the function keys settings, as per the man page and [mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/screen-users@gnu.org/msg01525.html), but have also tried using the default `ESC[n~`.

Comment: You don't say whether your PuTTY runs *on* Ubuntu or whether you merely run it, for example on Windows, to connect to Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm connecting to the web server from my PC, using PuTTY.

Answer (score 14):

Since you are using 10.04 I'll assume you are still using the `screen` backend to `byobu`. You should also learn the `screen` shortcuts - at least the most important ones.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> == create new window
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> == previous window
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> == next window
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> == toggle between two windows
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>[number]</kbd> == switch to window `[number]`
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> == detach from session

There are various reasons why this may not work. And you will encounter more the more different programs you use.

For example the default `byobu` shortcuts block out the ones in Midnight Commander (various F-keys), but you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[number]</kbd>, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> replaces <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Comment: Aah, okay I thought the F-keys would still work. I'm familiar with screen (it's what i've used for years) but the [Ctrl]+[a][c] does the same as [F2] - just flashes the screen. Works fine if I run screen manually, and not byobu.

Comment: Check your `.screenrc` and anything that gets sourced from it (did someone unbind the key?). Also consider global `screen` and `byobu` settings. btw: in my PuTTY to the same distro version I use backspace = `Control-?`, home = `Standard`, Function keys = `ESC[n~` ... and both `F2` and `Ctrl+a c` work for me.

Answer (score 3):

In Putty, You need to set the configurations:
-->Connection-->SSH-->Auth-->load ppk file
[image]
Replace the xterm with putty-256color

> **Connection->Data->Terminal-Type-String->** putty-256color
> [image]

> Note: Go to session-> click save button to save the configuration.